# How we Redirect one Page to AnotherPage with Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Code is

```
Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/ReportPage.aspx"));
```

Answer (score 3):

you don't need [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  here, since you have relative path you can directly call [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx)

```
Response.Redirect("~/ReportPage.aspx");
```

`Server.MapPath` will return physical path of given file. For example when we need to read TEXT file inside root folder

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/temp.txt"));
```

But in your case no need of a `Server.MapPath`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `MapPath` for this? Redirects are handled by the client so mapping to the physical file won't work.

Simply do:

```
Response.Redirect("~/ReportPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect`, redirects to the virtual path to a location not the physical path. Whereas `Server.MapPath` returns the physical path which is not valid in this context.

You just need to use like this

```
Response.Redirect("~/ReportPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Server.MapPath`.

```
Response.Redirect("~/ReportPage.aspx");
```